# Take specific value from database array using following php code

Tags: php, html, mysql

from the following code i want to take just a few value data from "elemen_desc" array. How to do it? I try to put if else statement in the option but the syntax is error. Maybe anyone can help? . Below is the following code.

```
public function ListElementDesc() {
        $document = new Document_Template_Model();
        $result = $document->ListElementDesc();
        $html = '';

        foreach ($result as $multi):
            $html .= '<option value="' . $multi['element_desc'] . '"></option>'; //' . $multi['element_code'] . '
        endforeach;

        return $html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see the syntax you did try that raised the error, however, perhaps this will help:

```
foreach ($result as $multi):
    if (isset($multi['element_desc'][1])):
        $html .= '<option value="' . $multi['element_desc'][1] . '"></option>'; //' . $multi['element_code'] . '
    else:
        $html .= '<option value="' . $multi['element_code'][0] . '"></option>'; //' . $multi['element_code'] . '
    endif;
endforeach;
```

For further reference perhaps this page will help, [PHP Alternative Syntax for Control Structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)